# Calendar loop repeating database loop in php

Tags: php, calendar

```
for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_master WHERE TASK_MASTER_SCHEDULE_DATE >='".$first_day_this_month."' AND TASK_MASTER_SCHEDULE_DATE <='".$last_day_this_month."' AND TASK_MASTER_UM_ID=5");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $sdate = date('j',strtotime($row['TASK_MASTER_SCHEDULE_DATE']));
        $taskdtl = substr($row['TASK_MASTER_ASSIGN_TASK_DTL'], 0, 5);
        $taskhr = $row['TASK_MASTER_HOURS'];
        if($sdate==$list_day)
        {
            if($taskhr >= '8')
            {
                $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day" style="background-color:green;">';
            }
            else
            {
                $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day" style="background-color:red;">';
            }
            $calendar .= $taskdtl;
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

            $calendar.= '</td>';
        }
        else
        {
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

            $calendar.= '</td>';
        }
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    }
endfor;
```

I am creating a calendar with insert my data into dates, if I have two task of today's date then that task should show in that day in calendar. Everything is working fine but when i am fetching data from database and if I have three rows then it repeats calendar loop three times.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `Continue;` in the end of your `else` condition.

[Continue PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: Than try to add a condition before your while loop to count the results if there is no results then execute the else condition, so try to add your else condition outside of the while loop maybe this will work for you :)